# How to do failable mapping of Dictionaries/Arrays to RealmSwift Objects

Tags: ios, json, swift, initialization, realm

### Context

We have some `[String: Any]` dictionaries and `[[String: Any]]` arrays coming from `JSONSerialization.jsonObject()` and we would like to make it class instances of [Realm `Object` models](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models) (let's say a `PersonModel` for below example). According to Realm documentation, we need to design models with properties like that:

```
class PersonModel : Object {
    dynamic var id = ""
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var imagePath: String?
    let friends = List<PersonModel>()
    let movies = List<MovieModel>()
}
```

### Our wishes for making the instances

- The creation of an instance based on a dictionary should be conditional: i.e. it should return a `Person?` because sometimes the data is invalid.
- The creation of a List based on an array should filter (or flatmap) valid objects only.
- The key names of the dictionary and the variable names of the class do not match: i.e. the JSON may have a "username" but the corresponding class variable would be "name". That's why we can't avoid a manual *mapping* solution of the dictionaries.

### Problems

- Unlike [Apple's recommendations on how to turn a JSON to an instance](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37),  `Realm.create(_:value:update:)` doesn't throw and never returns nil, which means it seems unable to deal with invalid data.
- We couldn't find any mapping implementation inside Realm. In fact, I believe Realm is asking, [according to its doc on json support](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#json), to deal with the validity of json data beforehand using third parties. Examples of those third parties could be find on [JSONShootout](https://github.com/bwhiteley/JSONShootout) and on ["Support custom model mappings" github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/694).

### Question

Let's say we have this `[[String:Any]]` array of dictionaries:

```
[["userid": "u1",
  "username": "bob",
  "image": "http://example.com/bob.jpg",
  "friendIds": ["u2", "u3"],
  "movieIds": ["sw4", "sw5", "sw6", "ro"]],
 ["userid": "u2",
  "username": "max",
  "image": "http://example.com/max.jpg",
  "friendIds": ["u1", "u3"],
  "movieIds": ["sw4", "sw5", "sw6", "sw7"]],
 ["userid": "u3",
  "username": false],
]
```

The desired result would be to have:

- no instance creation at all of a "u3" PersonModel, because it has invalid name.
- a PersonModel instance with name `"bob"` and friends being `List(max)`.
- a PersonModel instance with name `"max"` and friends being `List(bob)`.

But it's not obvious to us how we're supposed to achieve those conditions with RealmSwift. We don't see how to write code to workaround the non-fallible constructor `Realm.create(_:value:update:)`. And we don't see how third-parties JSON mappers (like [lyft/mapper](https://github.com/lyft/mapper) or [JohnSundell/Unbox](https://github.com/JohnSundell/Unbox)) can to the job of filtering/converting a given non appropriate `[[String:Any]]` to a `[[String:Any]]` compatible with RealmSwift `create()` method.

Comment: Hey - How did you do it then? We are planning to use Lyft Mapper with Realm.

Comment: @AsthaGupta I believe I let the instances being created by `Realm.create(_:value:update:)`, then I checked their validity and immediately deleted the incorrect ones.

Answer (score 0):

Katsumi from Realm here. We recommend using third-party mapping library to bind JSON to Realm model for now. I think ObjectMapper https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper provide failable initializer to validate JSON structure while mapping process. Is this answer for you?

Comment: Hi Katsumi. No, it doesn't answer perfectly well. In the question, we did gave links to [Realm's doc about JSON](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#json) and issue [#694](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/694), as we've read those. We gave an example, and were asking on the _how_ are any of those third parties going to solve the issues, expecting a demonstration that it can be solved.